# Confused by <T extends Class> behavior

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

So I have this `AbstractBook` Class

```
public abstract class AbstractBook<T extends AbstractPage> implements Serializable{
    public AbstractBook() {
    }

    public abstract void addPage(T var1);
}
```

and I have a sub class:

```
public class Book extends AbstractBook {

    private ArrayList<Page> allPages;
    private String title;

    Book(String title){
       allPages = new ArrayList<Page>();
    }

    @Override /** Doesn't Work */
    public void addPage(Page page) {
        this.allPages.add();
    }
}
```

In the subclass `addPage` method, I can't Override the method in the given form, because the parameter asks to be an `AbstractPage` type, even though `Page` is extended from `AbstractPage`:

```
public abstract class AbstractPage implements Serializable {
    public AbstractPage() {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Page extends AbstractPage {

  private String content;

  public Page(String Content){
    this.content = Content;
  }
}
```

- Why is that exactly?
- Isn't `T` defined as `<T extends AbstractPage>`, thus, `Page` should be an acceptable type for the parameter in `addPage` method ? It insists on compiler insists on `AbstractPage` type.
- Or does `<T extends AbstractPage>` not actually apply to the `T var1`
  in the `addPage` method ?
- But even then, what stops `addPage(Page page)` method from compiling?

Comment: You should declare `public class Book extends AbstractBook<Page>`

Comment: You have to define the generic tpye: public class Book extends AbstractBook <Page> {}

Comment: `public class Book extends AbstractBook<Page>` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are extending a raw type.

Change

```
public class Book extends AbstractBook
```

to

```
public class Book extends AbstractBook<Page>
```

Besides, `this.allPages.add();` should probably be `this.allPages.add(page);`.

Comment: Thank You!! I think I need to look more into the generic/raw types. And Oh yeah, I never finished writing that method.